# Поиск YII2 без GridView

Tags: php, yii2

Как организовать поиск, если представления такого вида?

```
 <?php foreach ($object as $item) : ?>
        <?php echo Html::img(Url::to('@web/' . $item->main_image), ['weight' => '300', 'height' => '300']) . '<br>'; ?>
        <?= 'Название: '.$item->title. '<br>'; ?>
        <?= 'Тип обьекта: '.$item->objectType->name . '<br>'; ?>
        <?= 'Подтип обьекта: '.$item->objectSubtype->name . '<br>'; ?>
        <?= 'Цена: '.$item->price. '<br>'; ?>
        <?= 'Валюта: '.$item->priceType->name. '<br>'; ?>
        <?= Html::a('Просмотр', ['view', 'id' => $item->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Редактировать', ['update', 'id' => $item->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= '<br>' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Если делать с GridView , то работает

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'title',
        'price',
    ],
]); ?>
```

Передаются параметры $dataProvider и $searchModel.

Так вот как их в цикл передать, эти параметры??

Comment: Просмотрите реализацию представления виджета `GridView`. Его "магия" заключается в том, что там есть хотя бы форма для поиска, а вы хотите сделать поиск без формы, так не получится.

Comment: Форма есть, при генерации crud с помощью gii создает файл _search. Вот такая форма у меня <?= $this->render('_search', [
        'model' => $searchModel,
    ]); ?> А чтобы передать параметр нужно было в цикле просто вот так прописать $dataProvider->getModels() as $item

Comment: вы, пожалуйста, следующий раз пишите подробнее.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно вывести не таблицей, а списком используйте [ListView](https://xn--d1acnqm.xn--j1amh/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/yii-2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-listview-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80).

Для вывода списка необходимо добавить в файл /project-folder/views/news/index.php следующий код:

```
<?php

use app\models\News;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => News::find()->where(['visibility'=>1])->orderBy('date DESC'),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);

echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_list',
]);
```

И создать файл для вывода записей по шаблону (файл: /project-folder/views/news/_list.php):

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;
?>

<div class="news-item">
    <h2><?= Html::encode($model->header) ?></h2>    
    <?= HtmlPurifier::process($model->text) ?>    
</div>
```